# Is this correct Context free grammar(CFG) for these two languages?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

Question 1: L = { 0^n 1^n | n > 0 }
My answer = S -> 0 S 1 | 10

Question 2: L = { 101^n0^2n | n > 0 }
My answer = S -> 101 S 00 | 100

Can anyone correct this if there is any issue with this CFG?[image]

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  We discourage "is my answer correct?" questions, as they are unlikely to be useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

First one seems correct. Second one is wrong because n > 0 so there must be at least two 1s in the string. The string 100 can't be derived from S. You need to add another non-terminal, say T such that T derives 1T00 or the empty string and S derives 101T00.

Comment: Correction above in 2nd question. There is 0^2n, not 0^2m. Now is this correct?

Comment: In my answer, I have written the grammar considering n instead of m. Even if it is n, your grammar is still wrong because S can derive the string 100 which doesn't follow the given pattern.